# Using live ubuntu environment USB for storage

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, storage

I created a bootable usb with a 32GB USB 2.0 flash drive. My question is, can I still use it for storing my files? If yes, how?

Comment: This totally depends on how you made the USB. mkusb will make a NTFS usbdata partition, Rufus and UNetbootin keep the Disk as writable FAT32. Ventoy keeps the disk as writable exFAT, Disks, Etcher SDC, dd, Win32DiskImager and a few others clone the iSO's image to a ISO9660 partition. A live USB can be used to turn part of that partition into writable NTFS or FAT32. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

### Make Bootable USB with No Wasted Space from Ubuntu.

There are several methods of making a bootable USB in Ubuntu.

Basic categories are Persistent install and Full install

For a comparison see: [Use Ubuntu on external hard drive in 2 different devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317083/use-ubuntu-on-external-hard-drive-in-2-different-devices/1317388#1317388) . Instructions for Full install USB are included.

The main reason to make a Persistent install is to create a USB that can be used to install Ubuntu.

The best tool for doing this is **mkusb**, see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb , mkusb will create a drive that will run Ubuntu and save between sessions, (Persistence), It can also create a NTFS **data** partition to be used by Linux or Windows like a normal USB.

[image]

[image]

The easiest tool for making a Live USB, that can be used for installing Ubuntu, comes with Ubuntu and is called **Startup Disk Creator**. It overwrites the whole disk as you mention in the question.

The useless space resulting from a **SDC** install can be easily converted to a NTFS or FAT32 data partition useful for data storage and transportation like mkusb.

**Procedure** Legacy Boot

- Run **Startup Disk Creator**, **dd**. **Disks** or **Etcher** to create Live 19.10, or later, USB
- Boot new Live USB to activate writable partition, (AKA casper-rw), then Power Off.
- Reboot the Live USB **toram**. (press `shift` when booting, hit `F6` and type a space and `toram`).
- Unmount writable/casper-rw partition using Disks.
- For **NTFS** open Terminal and run:

`sudo mkfs.ntfs -f -L data /dev/sdx3`

were x is the drive letter of the new Live USB

For **FAT32** use:

`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n data /dev/sdx1`

The drive should now have the original data space minus the size of the OS ISO.

**Procedure** UEFI Boot

Same as Legacy Boot however at GRUB menu press `e`. After the words `quiet splash` type a space then `toram`. Press `F10` to continue boot.