# Can we put other files rather than live os files in bootable usb?

Tags: boot, live-usb

I've been working on how to install live os(Ubuntu) on my usb. I've used Etcher but whole space is occupied by the Ubuntu when the procedure is complete. I want to add some of my daily used files on my usb but due to this I can't is there someway I can?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: The tool you use to write an ISO to media (*thumb-drive or other*)  determines how it goes there, some tools provide many options, others have fewer, but the type of ISO itself also matters (some allow options; some do not).

Comment: @guiverc thanks man it really help

Comment: Storing other data on the stick seems a Bad Idea. Most bootable-iso-install applications will wipe the entire USB stick, and install iso images update frequently (so you will be wiping the stick frequently),  A single mistake or typo when updating the stick will either render it unusable at a LiveUSB, or will lose all your data, or perhaps both. Much safer/simpler to obtain a second (appropriately-sized) USB stick for exclusive use by your Ubuntu LiveUSB.

Comment: If it's Ubuntu you're asking about; you should also provide release details; as Ubuntu ISOs vary depending on the release; as Ubuntu is built for multiple architectures & the boot process is altered so all architectures boot the same for a given release; meaning differences exist between releases (esp. recent releases & *live* ISOs).  This may not apply with non-Ubuntu ISOs, so OS/release matter (*many Ubuntu-based don't follow Ubuntu for example*), as does the version of the ISO writing tool used - it needs to match OS/release.

Comment: Bootable USB options see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1391796/43926

Comment: Using left over space from Live install, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327551/using-live-ubuntu-environment-usb-for-storage/1327634#1327634